# SQL SSMS 2017 Detailed result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m a bit newbie to SQL, so I want to ask for possible solution how to create a query which will show the desired results. 
There´s a table where are the data coming continuously from one main PLC so everything is gathered in 1 table. There are a bunch of data per 1 shift (about half million). In column "Op" are the machines represented by their IDs (Op = ID of machine). Machines are about from 1 to 218. Every machine has it´s their cycle times divided into starting process (T1), duration (T2), end process(T3) and Result. The "Result" can be interpreted as 0 - as OK, 1 - not OK, 2 - empty pallet, 3 - free flow of pallet. Those are the Results of what the PLCs are reporting directly into database´s table.

[image: https://i.ibb.co/nkmLkHG/palletOP.png]

I have tried the basic statements to count these results for exact record states (0,1,2,3) and for exact machine. That´s OK but not the desired goal.

```
SELECT Count(*) as Result0
FROM PalletOperations
where Op = 1 and Result = 0
```

The expected result is to show a full list of every machines from 1 to 218 how many results were counted as 0, 1, 2 and 3. The other columns are not relevant for this time. The main goal is to show a result as every machine has its own row with the expected data of counted states result. If theres 218 machines, than I need to generate results of 218 machines separately from 1 to 218 in rows. Each row should contain the Op(name 1,2,3,4....218) with the columns of counted result for states 0,1,2,3 as mentioned above.

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT op,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result_0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as result_3
FROM PalletOperations
GROUP BY op;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below sql statement to get count of results per machine per result

```
SELECT op,Result, count(*)
FROM PalletOperations
GROUP BY op,Result;
```